# npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.0.6 requires a peer xxxx but none is installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to run an angular project and getting below errors:

$ npm install
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.0.6 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.0.6 requires a peer of typescript@>=4.6.2 <4.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/animations@9.1.13 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.1.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/common@9.1.13 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.1.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/core@14.0.6 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.11.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@9.1.13 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.1.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@9.1.13 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.1.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.13 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.1.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@9.1.13 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.1.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/service-worker@9.1.13 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.1.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngrx/effects@9.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngrx/store@9.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@14.0.6 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@14.0.6 requires a peer of typescript@>=4.6.2 <4.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN acorn-import-assertions@1.8.0 requires a peer of acorn@^8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-mydatepicker@0.5.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@5.1.3 requires a peer of @popperjs/core@^2.10.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-prettier@8.5.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

up to date in 4.872s

183 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

The node version in my system is as followed:
Angular CLI: 14.0.6
Node: 14.17.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13
OS: win32 x64

here is the angular version in my project :
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/core": "^14.0.6",
"@angular/forms": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/router": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.13",
"@ng-idle/core": "^11.1.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^9.1.1",
"@ngrx/store": "^9.1.1",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^9.1.1",
"angular-mydatepicker": "^0.5.7",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"core-js": "^2.6.10",
"crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
"ng-swagger-gen": "^0.10.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
"ngx-editor": "^9.0.2",
"ngx-pagination": "^3.3.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.0",
"rxjs": "^6.5.3",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution you could use a notation "Patch releases"

```
As Is: "@angular/core": "^14.0.6", 
To Be: "@angular/core": "~14.0.6",
```